# pandas resampling dataframe and keep datetime index as a column

Tags: pandas, pivot

I'm trying to resample daily data to weekly data using pandas.

I'm using the following:

```
weekly_start_date =pd.Timestamp('01/05/2011')
weekly_end_date =pd.Timestamp('05/28/2013')

daily_data = daily_data[(daily_data["date"] >= weekly_start_date) & (daily_data["date"] <= weekly_end_date)]    

daily_data = daily_data.set_index('date',drop=False)
weekly_data = daily_data.resample('7D',how=np.sum,closed='left',label='left')
```

The problem is weekly_data doesn't have the date column anymore.

What did I miss?

Thanks,

Comment: What would you want the date column to have here? It's been resampled (weekly) via sum, I don't think it makes sense to have the date anymore. What were you hoping for?

Comment: @Andy I'm hoping for to get the 1st date in the week, as week commencing for example

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question, it looks like your doing the resampling correctly (Pandas docs on resampling here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

```
  weekly_data = daily_data.resample('7D',how=np.sum,closed='left',label='left')
```

If the only issue is that you'd like the DateTimeIndex replicated in a column you can just do this.

```
  weekly_data['date'] = weekly_data.index.values
```

Apologies if I misunderstood the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only resample by numeric columns:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.Timestamp('1/1/2012'), 1, 'a', [1]], [pd.Timestamp('1/2/2012'), 2, 'b', [2]]], columns=['date', 'no', 'letter', 'li'])

In [12]: df1 = df.set_index('date', drop=False)

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
                          date  no letter   li
date
2012-01-01 2012-01-01 00:00:00   1      a  [1]
2012-01-02 2012-01-02 00:00:00   2      b  [2]

In [15]: df1.resample('M', how=np.sum)
Out[15]:
            no
date
2012-01-31   3
```

We can see that it uses the dtype to determine whether it's numeric:

```
In [16]: df1.no = df1.no.astype(object)

In [17]: df1.resample('M', how=sum)
Out[17]:
            date  no  letter  li
date
2012-01-31     0   0       0   0
```

An awful hack for actual summing:

```
In [21]: rng = pd.date_range(weekly_start_date, weekly_end_date, freq='M')

In [22]: g = df1.groupby(rng.asof)

In [23]: g.apply(lambda t: t.apply(lambda x: x.sum(1))).unstack()
Out[23]:
                           date no letter      li
2011-12-31  2650838400000000000  3     ab  [1, 2]
```

*The date is the sum of the epoch nanoseconds...*

(Hopefully I'm doing something silly, and there's is an easier way!)

Comment: you could do say median of the dates in the re sample interval if u really wanted

Comment: @Jeff I was thinking as I wrote first line it was a bit of a lie :s

Comment: Thanks Andy. All the values in my dataframe are numeric. The resampling is working in my code. But I need the date as a column in my resampled df. I don't get that when I resample using "7D". The date column is dropped

Comment: @user2484945 date isn't numeric though (it's a date)? Could you give a small example we can see which shows your issue + what you want?

Comment: @user2484945 Do you mind editing that into your question (can't do formatting well in the comments) :)

Comment: @Andy please find my reply below. Thanks