# How to modify the time labels of pandas.series.resample?

Tags: pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'mark': ['A']*6,
    'date': ['2021-02-01', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-09-30', '2021-12-30'],
    'prop': np.arange(0.1, 0.7, 0.1)})
df1
```

```
  mark        date  prop
0    A  2021-02-01   0.1
1    A  2021-03-31   0.2
2    A  2021-04-01   0.3
3    A  2021-06-01   0.4
4    A  2021-09-30   0.5
5    A  2021-12-30   0.6
```

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
tmp = df1.set_index(['date'])
tmp['prop'].resample('Q', closed='left').first()
```

result is:

```
date
2021-03-31    0.1
2021-06-30    0.2
2021-09-30    NaN
2021-12-31    0.5
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: prop, dtype: float64
```

I want the timestamp to display as the original time, such as

```
2021-02-01    0.1
2021-03-31    0.2
NaN           NaN
2021-09-30    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have holes in your original data then I don't think resampling is helping here. Here is the simplest solution:

### create quarters

```
df1['Q'] = df1.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).quarter)
df1
Out[67]: 
  mark        date  prop  Q
0    A  2021-02-01   0.1  1
1    A  2021-03-31   0.2  1
2    A  2021-04-01   0.3  2
3    A  2021-06-01   0.4  2
4    A  2021-09-30   0.5  3
5    A  2021-12-30   0.6  4
```

### cumsum by quarters

```
df1['q_sum'] = df1.groupby('Q', as_index=False)['prop'].cumsum()
df1
Out[71]: 
  mark        date  prop  Q  q_sum
0    A  2021-02-01   0.1  1    0.1
1    A  2021-03-31   0.2  1    0.3
2    A  2021-04-01   0.3  2    0.3
3    A  2021-06-01   0.4  2    0.7
4    A  2021-09-30   0.5  3    0.5
5    A  2021-12-30   0.6  4    0.6
```

### or cummax

```
df1['q_sum']=df1.groupby('Q',as_index=False)['prop'].cummax()

df1
Out[74]: 
  mark        date  prop  Q  q_sum
0    A  2021-02-01   0.1  1    0.1
1    A  2021-03-31   0.2  1    0.2
2    A  2021-04-01   0.3  2    0.3
3    A  2021-06-01   0.4  2    0.4
4    A  2021-09-30   0.5  3    0.5
5    A  2021-12-30   0.6  4    0.6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result seems to be incorrect, generating a lot of null values.

Comment: cummax is more close to what you are after

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `prop`, you could use the original index, then use the result to reindex `df1`.

```
tmp1 = df1.reset_index(names='index').set_index('date')
idx = tmp1['index'].resample('Q', closed='left').first()
df1.reindex(idx).set_index('date')['prop']
```

```
date
2021-02-01    0.1
2021-03-31    0.2
NaT           NaN
2021-09-30    0.5
Name: prop, dtype: float64
```

Comment: P.S. I posted [another answer I think is better](/a/77294900/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

Based on some existing questions<sup>*</sup>, it looks like the easiest way to keep the dates is to copy them to another column, for example:

```
(tmp.assign(date=tmp.index)
    .resample('Q', closed='left').first()
    .set_index('date')['prop'])
```

```
date
2021-02-01    0.1
2021-03-31    0.2
NaT           NaN
2021-09-30    0.5
Name: prop, dtype: float64
```

---

*
[Resample in pandas without changing date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34663895/4518341),
[pandas resampling dataframe and keep datetime index as a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17185942/4518341)